Swagger Codegen: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connexion.apps.flask_app'
In my app I upgraded connexion (2.14.2=>3.0.6), flask (2.2.5=>3.0.3) and werkzeug (2.2.3=>3.0.2) and of course all required/depending libs. I use the SwaggerHub to generate a Python client and server (flask) stub. But the generated code doesn't work with the upgraded versions as the following error occurs:
2024-04-16 14:13:22,701 [MainThread          ] ERROR    root                           - Failed with exception: No module named 'connexion.apps.flask_app'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neoctl\src\main\main.py", line 523, in main
  File "neoctl\src\main\main.py", line 191, in init
  File "neoctl\src\modules\restserver\run.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "neoctl\src\generated\server\swagger_server\encoder.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connexion.apps.flask_app'

The "connexion.apps.flask_app" module seems to be renamed to "connexion.apps.flask".
Any idea how to get the generated SwaggerHub code back working?
Any help appreciated! Thanks!

I was able to fix this by doing pip install 'connexion<3.0.0' it looks like 3.0.0 doesn't have 'connexion.apps.flask_app'

Thanks, that's exactly the way I did. But connexion 2.14.2 was released at Jan23. Of course, my aim is to be up to date with all used 3rd party libs. Therefore, I hope there is another solution.
